# Google Cloud Storage API write Limits

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Reading the documentation on [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#requests) I am still not clear of the following points:

1. Are there any limits on the size of the API request to the Google cloud Storage bucket? (We need to transfer PDFs from a CRM to Google Cloud Storage)
2. How many files we can send (it mentions a limit of 1000 writes per second) is that the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are the [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#objects) you store in Cloud Storage, so [the maximum size limit 5 TB](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) should be considered for individual files. There is no limit to write across multiple objects, however buckets support roughly 1000 writes per second and then scale up as needed.

For parallel uploads, please take note that up to 32 objects/files can be composed in a single composition request and a per-project composition rate limit of approximately 1,000 source objects per second.

I also recommend that you take a look at [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#best-practices) on how to ramp up the request rate

Answer (score 0):

You go with more than 1000 writes per second per bucket - the GCS infrastructure will scale automatically to accommodate it. The only requirement is not to ramp up the load too quickly, namely "double the request rate no faster than every 20 minutes".

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#ramp-up